# How can I display the first word of a series of words that ends with a semicolon?

Tags: c#

My application gets phrases from a database. These strings can look like this:

```
house; home; residence
cat
dog
```

How can I format these strings so that the resulting output looks like:

```
house
cat 
dog
```

In other words if there's a semicolon immediately following the first word I would like to just include from the start up to the end of the semicolon and if no semicolon then just include the first word.

Comment: What have u tried so far??

Comment: Have you looked at String.Split(';')?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How did you get *4.981 rep* and *33 gold* ?

Comment: @Jim he seems to just ask numerous basic questions.. which get a lot of attention.. community responds to easy questions afterall.. perhaps it is a deliberate effort; 

but, it drives the community and engages developers who would otherwise not participate in specific, ambiguous issues.. so it's difficult for me to denounce it.

Comment: @BrettCaswell there is not a problem with easy questions. The question does not provide anything that looks like an *effort*, and the actual explanation of the question makes only half sense *if there's a semicolon immediately following the first word I would like to just include from the start up to the end of the semicolon and if no semicolon then just include the first word*. A user with this amount rep/g/s/b should know how to ask a question properly.

Comment: if is the string were "house home", what would you want to see in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string str = "house; home; residence";
string firstWord = str.Split(';').FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This doesn't achieve the goal

Comment: no point in looking for the space character, and would cause needless issues in supporting two word records.

Comment: Would this also work for the case where there was no ; character?

Comment: Thanks @BrettCaswell, I think I misread the question initially.

Comment: @Alan, yes if there is no ';' the split would return the whole string

Comment: though, I agree that the question says first 'word'.. that's probably a unintentional term..

Comment: This answer was *completely* incorrect when it was first submitted :/

Comment: @mayu it probably resembles the OP's scope (iterating in a reader and handling the assignment to a property being initiated or something to that effect).. there are two other manners to handle this operating, one is on the entire collection after assignment (when your answer would have been more applicable) and in the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var list = new List<string>() { "house; home; residence", "cat", "dog", "", null };

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item} -> {item?.Split(';').FirstOrDefault()}");
        }
```

produces

```
house; home; residence -> house
cat -> cat
dog -> dog
 ->
 ->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `string.IndexOf(";")` and get all from `0` toindexOf `;`.

Comment: not going to negative this, but you should not have to do so much conditional checks and substring for this purpose.. `string.Split` is the proper method here, because it handles the conditional check and `string.Substring` operation in one call. it will result in a collection with one instance if the string doesn't contain the delimiter.